# Can we deploy application to multiple Vms on multiple clouds with Github Actions?

Tags: azure-devops, virtual-machine, devops, github-actions, continuous-deployment

I have an application which I want to deploy to a number of VMS on Azure and AWS, I was working with Azure DevOps before and it provided very nice features to achieve this with deployment groups etc. Now I want to work with Github and I am really having problems to design my CI CD pipeline since Github actions do not have any feature which could be used to do deployment on a set of VMS. If there are please guys share your thoughts any article would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can firstly consider to deploy application to one Virtual Machine with Github Actions.

1. Just in the environment of **Azure**, all you need is to use GitHub Action to build a virtual machine (VM) within Azure.

you can learn the detailed steps to deploy application to **one** Virtual Machine with Github Actions in：[How to use GitHub Actions to deploy an Azure Virtual Machine](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/how-to-use-github-actions-to-deploy-an-azure-virtual-machine/ba-p/1092015).

2. For multi-environment deployments either in Azure or AWS with GitHub Actions, I recommend you to use [Octopus Deploy](https://octopus.com/docs/getting-started) as a reference. you can still refer to [Multi-environment deployments with GitHub Actions and Octopus](https://octopus.com/blog/multi-environment-deployments-github-actions) to deploy Virtual Machine on AWS.
3. For

> deploy application to multiple Vms

We recommend you to use [Azure Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-technical-overview) to run parallel workloads. It can allow you to deploy application to multiple Vms at one time in batch in the basic of *deploy application to **one** Virtual Machine*.

You can run the batch job using Azure CLI by following the example: [Run  Batch job with the Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/quick-create-cli).